# how can we make kernel boot to the login prompt or shell without initramfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, boot

For example in a videa about u-boot, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INWghYZH3hI, near time 43:01, I see the lecturer gives u-boot the kernel address and fdt address but not the initramfs address. (bootz 0x80000000 - 0x80800000) but linux boots to the login prompt and he can log in.
How come this is possible? I understand after the kernel boots it starts init process in the initramfs.(I forgot there were a precedence). Without initramfs, how is it possible to run login process or shell?
(it's related to programming so I ask it here. If requested I can move it to unix stackexchange. Is there a method of moving a question to somerewhere else automatically? guess not..)

Comment: Without an initramfs, the kernel needs to be told which block device contains the root filesystem, then it can mount it, locate the init binary, and execute it as process 1.

Comment: Of course, in order for the kernel to do what I wrote above, the required block device drivers and file system drivers for mounting the root file system need to be compiled as built-in, not as modules.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no initramfs?  *"I see the lecturer gives u-boot the kernel address and fdt address but not the initramfs address"* -- The cpio archive for populating the initramfs can be linked with the kernel image as one image file, so a separate file is not needed during boot.

Comment: Thank you Ian Abobott and sawdust, I can now understand. I checked the video and saw near 40:29, the boot command line was "root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait console=tty0e,115200", so sd card was containing root filesystem. Anyone of you can post it as an answer if you want so I can select it.

Comment: @sawdust Yes I recently learned how to include initramfs.cpio.gz into the kernel image using CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE assigment in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I learned from the comments with combination with my previous knowledge.
you can embed the initramfs.tar.gz file in the kernel binary image using CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=nitramfs.cpio.gz in the configuration. (menuconfig). The initramfs image is placed at the end of the kernel image maybe (I remember).
But this was not the case in the youtube video I mentioned in my question. Near 40:29 in the video, the kernel boot command is shown to have "root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait console=tty0e,115200".  So it's telling the kernel to use SD card 0's partition 1 as the root system after boot, instead of using initramfs.(when you want to use initramfs, you specify root=/dev/ram and pass the initramfs location. in qemu you use -initrd initramfs.cpio.gz option, or in real machine this information is passed through the device tree to the kernel, in the `chosen` node's initrd-start and initrd-end address.).